# Como usar o JUNIT para testar metodos void da minha classe DAO

Tags: java, sql, testes-de-unidade, junit

Olá tenho uma classe DAO e quero implementar testes com JUNIT,porem muitos dos metodos tem o retorno void.
Aqui vai um pedaço da classe que compõe o pacote DAO

```
public class ExemplarDAO {

private Connection connection = null;

public ExemplarDAO() {
    connection = Conexao.getConexao();
}

public void Inserir(Exemplar exemplar) {
    try {
        String sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO `exemplar`(`ID_EXE`, `ISBN`, `LiberadoParaEmprestimo`, `Duracao`, `QuantidadePaginas`, `FK_TITULO`)\n"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, exemplar.getIdExe());
        ps.setString(2, exemplar.getIsbn());
        ps.setBoolean(3, exemplar.getLiberadoParaEmprestimo());
        ps.setString(4, exemplar.getDuracao());
        ps.setString(5, exemplar.getQuantidadePaginas());
        ps.setInt(6, exemplar.getFkTitulo());

        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aqui a classe exemplar

```
public class Exemplar {

private int idExe;

private int fkTitulo;

private String isbn;

private Boolean liberadoParaEmprestimo;

private String duracao;

private String quantidadePaginas;

private Titulo titulo;

public Exemplar() {
}

public Exemplar(int idExe, int fkTitulo, String isbn, Boolean liberadoParaEmprestimo, String duracao, String quantidadePaginas) {
    this.idExe = idExe;
    this.fkTitulo = fkTitulo;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.liberadoParaEmprestimo = liberadoParaEmprestimo;
    this.duracao = duracao;
    this.quantidadePaginas = quantidadePaginas;
}



public int getIdExe() {
    return idExe;
}

public void setIdExe(int idExe) {
    this.idExe = idExe;
}

public int getFkTitulo() {
    return fkTitulo;
}

public void setFkTitulo(int fkTitulo) {
    this.fkTitulo = fkTitulo;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public Boolean getLiberadoParaEmprestimo() {
    return liberadoParaEmprestimo;
}

public void setLiberadoParaEmprestimo(Boolean liberadoParaEmprestimo) {
    this.liberadoParaEmprestimo = liberadoParaEmprestimo;
}

public String getDuracao() {
    return duracao;
}

public void setDuracao(String duracao) {
    this.duracao = duracao;
}

public String getQuantidadePaginas() {
    return quantidadePaginas;
}

public void setQuantidadePaginas(String quantidadePaginas) {
    this.quantidadePaginas = quantidadePaginas;
}

public Titulo getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(Titulo titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
```

Como preparo o JUNIT neste caso?

Comment: No teste: crie uma instância de *Exemplar* e passe para o método *Inserir*; depois faça um select na tabela onde deveria ter sido inserido o objeto e compare o registro encontrado na base com os dados do objeto Exemplar passado por parâmetro. Certifique-se de que a base esteja em um estado conhecido, por exemplo deletando todos os registros da tabela antes de iniciar o teste ou fazendo rollback da transação ao final do teste. Certifique-se de que a base não estará sendo usada durante os testes, por exemplo usando uma base exclusiva para os testes automatizados.

Comment: O que você estará testando, neste caso, é se o Dao fez o mapeamento correto e se o comando insert funciona. Dicas: **a)** é melhor deixar a gestão da conexão com o consumidor do Dao,  em vez de deixar no Dao em si, assim o teste também pode gerenciar a conexão apontando para uma base exclusiva de testes. **b)** remova este *try-catch* pois a única coisa que ele faz por você aí é dificultar o diagnóstico de problemas.

Comment: Obrigado ^^ e isto mesmo que queria

Comment: @Caffé porque não publicar uma resposta para essa pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

No teste:

- crie uma instância de Exemplar e passe para o método `Inserir`;
- depois faça um select na tabela onde deveria ter sido inserido o objeto e compare o registro encontrado na base com os dados do objeto `Exemplar` passado por parâmetro.
- Certifique-se de que a base esteja em um estado conhecido, por exemplo deletando todos os registros da tabela antes de iniciar o teste ou fazendo *rollback* da transação ao final do teste.
- Certifique-se de que a base não estará sendo usada durante os testes, por exemplo usando uma base exclusiva para os testes automatizados.

O que você estará testando, neste caso, é se o Dao fez o mapeamento correto e se o comando insert funciona.

Dicas:

1. é melhor deixar a gestão da conexão com o consumidor do Dao, em
   vez de deixar no `Dao` em si, assim o teste também pode gerenciar a
   conexão apontando para uma base exclusiva de testes.
2. remova este `try-catch` pois a única coisa que ele faz por você aí
   é dificultar o diagnóstico de problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Deve se ter cuidado com testes em DAOs. Os testes unitários devem testar a lógica. Por isso deve ter um ambiente controlado. As entradas e as saídas desses métodos devem ser repetíveis, retestáveis, confiáveis. Quando essas entradas ou resultados podem alterar por fatores externos (ex: o dados na base mudam) seu teste não é considerado confiável. Seu teste corre o risco de precisar ser refatorado com frequência.

O ideal é que o serviço DAO que iria na base (exemplarDAO.inserir) fosse mockado. Se ainda sim quiser testar nesse seu caso, o ideal é que o seu 'Conexao' seja mockado e seja usado o '**when**' do junit para simular o comportamento.

Outro método que também pode ser usado por ser um método void é o '**verify**', em que você controla os pontos por onde o processamento passou.

Aqui dois tópicos no stackoverflow sobre esse assunto:

- [Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)
- [Mockito : how to verify method was called on an object created within a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method)